e.nativeEvent.offsetX is 0 on mouseMove inside setState function
I have the following code that gets the cursor position on a canvas element. The code works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox, the e.nativeEvent.offsetX is 0 inside the set state function and outside is normal.
I know that the solution would be to store the offsets and then use them, but I'm curious if this is a bug or why it is not "supposed" to work.
Thank you
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const DataFirefoxNotWorking = () => {
  const [properties, setProperties] = useState(() => ({
    key1: 0,
    key2: 0,
    key4: 0,
    key3: 0,
    coordinates: { x: null, y: null },
  }));
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  const mouseMove = (e) => {
    console.log({ x: e.nativeEvent.offsetX, y: e.nativeEvent.offsetY }); // This are shown correctly
    setProperties((oldProperties) => ({
      ...oldProperties,
      coordinates: { x: e.nativeEvent.offsetX, y: e.nativeEvent.offsetY },
      // In Firefox this two are 0
      // In Chrome works
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 300;
    canvas.height = 500;
    ctx.font = "50px Arial";
    ctx.strokeText(`x: ${properties.coordinates.x}`, 10, 50);
    ctx.strokeText(`y: ${properties.coordinates.y}`, 10, 100);
  }, [properties.coordinates]);

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas
        style={{ position: "relative" }}
        ref={canvasRef}
        onMouseMove={mouseMove}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataFirefoxNotWorking;

